# The name 'u8' does not exist in the current context in ASP.NET Core Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I try to build ASP.NET Core source code for `Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers` but got lots of errors due to some code like below. How can I fix it please? The IDE that I am using is Visual Studio 2022 Community. The language version shows preview.

```
private static ReadOnlySpan<byte> MimePrefix => "\"=?utf-8?B?"u8;
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the format is not correct,what is the type of `"\"=?utf-8?B?"u8`?

Comment: It's C# 11 new feature actually. I did not notice it until today.  @YiyiYou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a new feature of C# 11 - [Utf8 Strings Literals](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/utf8-string-literals.md#u8-suffix-on-string-literals):

```
string s1 = "hello"u8;             // Error
var s2 = "hello"u8;                // Okay and type is byte[]
Span<byte> s3 = "hello"u8;         // Okay due to an implicit user-defined conversion from byte[] declared on Span<byte>.
ReadOnlySpan<byte> s3 = "hello"u8; // Okay due to an implicit user-defined conversion from byte[] declared on ReadOnlySpan<byte>.
```

and the feature is [merged](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/58848) into Visual Studio 17.3p1.

Just like the [commit's](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/41449) author talk:

> Also, folks likely need to update VS for the feature to light up.

Comment: You have saved my day. The feature is not available in VS 2022 Release but Preview.

Answer (score 0):

After reading [`Encoded-word Syntax`](https://dmorgan.info/posts/encoded-word-syntax/), I still don't know what you want, so please just tell me what kind of string you need and I will help you further.

**You can refer to the following code first:**

```
private static string MimePrefix => "\"=?utf-8?B?\"u8"; // '=?utf-8?B?'u8
private static ReadOnlySpan<byte> MimePrefix1 => Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("=?utf-8?B?");
```

Comment: thanks Jason for your reply. that is C# 11 new feature actually.